# How to remove duplicate legend entries w/ plotly subplots()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, subplot, r-plotly

How can I remove the duplicates in my legend when using plotly's subplots()?

Here is my MWE:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

mpg %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  do(p = plot_ly(., x = ~cyl, y = ~displ, color = ~trans, type = 'bar')) %>%
  subplot(nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE, titleX = TRUE) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'stack')
```

Comment: mpg is a dataset included in ggplot2 library. No need for dput()

Comment: since there is no `class` with all the different `trans` levels and `plotly` does not have faceting like `ggplot2` I can only think of using `facet_wrap` with `ggplot2` and then `ggplotly` to make a `plotly` object with one legend only. If that works for you, I can post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another workaround using the `tidyverse`. The following steps are added to the original MWE:

- Convert the `trans` column to a factor.
- Use tidyr's `complete` to fill (non-NA) dummy values for the missing factor levels in each `class` group.
- Follow M-M's suggestion setting `showlegend` to `TRUE` for a single group and `legendgroup` to `trans` to link the legend entries between subplots.

```r
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>%
    mutate_at("trans", as.factor) %>%  
    group_by(class) %>%
    group_map(.f = ~{          
          ## fill missing levels w/ displ = 0, cyl = first available value 
          complete(.x, trans, fill = list(displ = 0, cyl = head(.x$cyl, 1))) %>%
          plot_ly(x = ~cyl, y = ~displ, color = ~trans, colors = "Paired", type = "bar",
              showlegend = (.y == "2seater"), legendgroup = ~trans) %>%
          layout(yaxis = list(title = as.character(.y)), barmode = "stack")
        }) %>%
    subplot(nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE, titleY = TRUE)
```

[image: plotly_plot]

Comment: @Joris_Chau thanks for your great answer! Maybe you can help me with this one too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57672160/plotly-scaley-not-working-across-subplot-rows

Answer (score 6):

`plotly` does not have `facet` like `ggplot2` so it will add legend for each `subplot` or you can turn it off for some of them.

Here we do not have a layer with all the `~class` entries nor two plots with no intersection in `class` which their combination also covers all of them. In that case, we could set `showlegend` to `TRUE` for those specific plot(s) and set it to `FALSE` for the rest and also set the `legendgroup` to `trans` so we get a unique but also complete legend.

As I said, here we do not have that special case. So What I can think of are two possibilities:

1. Adding the whole data (duplicating whole dataframe) and assigning class of `All` to them. Then plotting that along with original data but keep the legend only for `class == All`.
2. Using `ggplot::facet_wrap` and then `ggplotly` to make a `plotly` object. However, this would cause some issues with `x-axis` (compare `ggplot` object to `plotly` ones).

```r
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

```
ly_plot <-  . %>% 
             plot_ly(x = ~cyl, y = ~displ, color = ~trans, 
                     type = 'bar', showlegend = ~all(legendC)) %>%
              add_annotations(
              text = ~unique(class),
              x = 0.5,
              y = 1,
              yref = "paper",
              xref = "paper",
              xanchor = "middle",
              yanchor = "top",
              showarrow = FALSE,
              font = list(size = 15))

mpg %>%
  mutate(class= "_All_") %>% 
  rbind(.,mpg) %>% 
  mutate(legendC = (class == "_All_")) %>% 
  group_by(class) %>%
  do(p = ly_plot(.)) %>%
  subplot(nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE, titleX = TRUE) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'stack')

#> Warning in RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2"): n too large, 
#>  allowed maximum for palette Set2 is 8
#> Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors
```

[image]

```r
p <- ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x=cyl, y=displ, fill=trans))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +
      facet_wrap(~class)
p
```

[image]

```r
ggplotly(p) #seems for this we should also set "colour = trans"
```

[image]